# Check if an alias exist in keystore

Tags: java, linux, shell, keystore, keytool

I am new to shell scripting, I have a script that is used to import cert and import keystore using keytool. This script is inside a Pod, there are times when I have to restart my pod and sometimes when this script runs I get this error

> Existing entry alias server exists, overwrite? [no]:  Enter new alias
> name  (RETURN to cancel import for this entry):

I know that there is command to list the alias

```
keytool -list  -keystore keystore.jks -storepass changeit -alias server
```

which gives the output

> server, Jun 22, 2022, PrivateKeyEntry,
> Certificate fingerprint (SHA-256): AC:DC:12:...

for an alias it that is not there, this command gives an exception

> keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Alias  does not exist

Is there a way in which I can write a check if the an keystore alias exists, if not allow the  *keytool -importcert* command to execute ? Are there any return codes that I can compare to move forward with the execution ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$?` to find the return value of the last executed command.
0 return value means success, otherwise, in case of exception, you get a number other then 0.

```bash
keytool -list -keystore keystore.jks -storepass changeit -alias server

if [[ $? = 0 ]]; then
        echo "alias is present"
else
        echo "alias is not present"
fi
```

**EDIT**
As Charles Duffy points out the use of `$?` [is discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313216/why-is-testing-to-see-if-a-command-succeeded-or-not-an-anti-pattern).
You can simply use

```bash
if keytool -list -keystore keystore.jks -storepass changeit -alias server; then
        echo "alias is present"
else
        echo "alias is not present"
fi
```

Comment: [Why is using `$?` to test if a command succeeded or not an antipattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313216/why-is-testing-to-see-if-a-command-succeeded-or-not-an-anti-pattern)

Comment: Instead, just use `if keytoool ...; then echo "alias is present"; else echo "alias is not present"; fi`.

Comment: this gives me a result like this:

when the alias is present, 

*server, Jun 22, 2022, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA-256): AC:05:ED:86
Warning:
The JKS keystore uses a proprietary format. It is recommended to migrate to PKCS12 which is an industry standard format using "keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore keystore.jks -destkeystore keystore.jks -deststoretype pkcs12". 

alias is present *

<br/>

When the alias is not there, there is an exception

bash-4.2$ ./test.sh
*keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Alias <serverabc> does not exist
alias is not present*

Comment: Have you tried redirecting the output command? ```if keytool ... > /dev/null; then echo "alias is present"; else echo "alias is not present"; fi```